# Vanishing of terms in power series expansion

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

I am looking to find the power series expansion around $0$ of the rational function defined by $$f(z)=\prod_{l=0}^n (1-lz)^{(-1)^l {n\choose l}}.$$
By considering small $n$, I am led believe that the coefficients $a_r$ of the power series expansion satisfy $a_0=1$, $a_r=0$ for $0<r<n$, and $a_n=1+(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)! z^n$. I would like to see a quick proof of this statement (using any methods you like, the shorter the better), having tried e.g. residue theorem and induction in vain.

Presumably this comes down to a certain identity between binomial coefficients?

Comment: Why don't you actually apply the product rule and take the derivative? Collect like terms, etc....

Comment: In fact the stronger claim

$$
\prod_{l=0}^\infty(1-lz)^{(-1)^l\binom n{l-k}}=1+(-1)^{n+k}(n-1)!z^n+O\left(z^{n+1}\right)
$$

seems to hold; but this is still not enough for a proof by induction.

Comment: Combinatorially speaking, the coefficient of $z^k$ in the product without the alternating signs counts the unordered $k$-tuples of memberships in distinct subsets of an $n$-element set (a membership being a pair $(x,S)$ with $x\in S$). Apparently these counts are equal for $0\lt k\lt n$ if you restrict them to subsets with odd and even numbers of elements, respectively. I suspect there should be a nice combinatorial proof for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work with the logarithm, then exponentiate.
$$\log(f(z))= \sum_{m=0}^{n} (-1)^m\binom{n}{m}\log(1-m\,z)=\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^{m+1}\binom{n}{m} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(m\,z)^k}{k}.$$
Exchange summations in the last expression; first one has upper finite summation limit, so its O.K. 
$$\log(f(z))=  -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k}\sum_{m=0}^n(-1)^{m}\binom{n}{m} m^k.$$
It is well known (differentiate the binomial theorem) that the inside sum is 0 for $k<n$ and has the value $(-1)^n\,n!$ for $k=n.$ Thus
$\log(f(z))= -(-1)^n\,z^n(n-1)!+O(z^{n+1}).$  Exponentiation gives the result of the OP's that
$$f(z) = 1  +z^n(n-1)!(-1)^{n-1}+O(z^{n+1}), $$

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Partial Answer

I've got it down to a complicated binomial sum.

---

Let $m_i=(-1)^i\binom{n}i$ be the exponent of the $i^\text{th}$ factor, for ease of notation. The following property of $m_i$ is almost certainly useful:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^ni^rm_i = 0\qquad\text{for }0<r<n\tag{1}
$$
Onto the problem at hand. Using the Leibniz rule for the $r^\text{th}$ derivative of a product of $n$ functions, 
$$
f^{(r)}(0) = \sum_{k_1+\dots+k_n=r}\binom{r}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n}\prod_{l=1}^n\frac{d^{k_i}}{dz^{k_i}}\bigg|_{z=0}(1-i z)^{m_i}
$$
Repeated differentiation introduces a falling factorial. Using Knuth's notation $x^{\underline n}=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$, we have
$$
\frac{d^{k_l}}{dz^{k_l}}\bigg|_{z=0}(1-i z)^{m_i}=(-i)^{k_l}(m_i)^{\underline{k_l}},
$$
so
$$
\boxed{f^{(r)}(0) = (-1)^r\!\!\!\!\!\sum_{k_1+\dots+k_n=r}\binom{r}{k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n}1^{k_1}(m_1)^{\underline{k_1}}\,2^{k_2}(m_2)^{\underline{k_2}}\cdots n^{k_n}(m_n)^{\underline{k_n}}}\tag{2}
$$
This looks suspiciously like the multinomial expansion of $(m_1+2m_2+\dots+nm_n)^r$. The problem is that some of the exponents are replaced by falling factorials.

---

I've tried to expand this out for small values of $r$ (ignoring the $(-1)^r$ out front) and look for a pattern. When $r=1$, the sum is just $\sum_i im_i$, which by (1) is zero when $n>1$. When $r=2$, you get
$$
\sum_i i^2m_i(m_i-1) + \sum_{i\neq j}im_i jm_j=\left(\sum_i im_i\right)^2-\sum_i i^2m_i
$$
Applying $(1)$ twice, with $r=1,2$, the above is zero for $n>2$. Things get a little messier when $r=3$:
$$
\sum_{i}i^3 m_i(m_i-1)(m_i-2) + 3\sum_{i\neq j}i^2m_i(m_i-1)jm_j + \sum_{i\neq j\neq k\neq i}im_ijm_jkm_k
$$
We can collect all of the cubic terms nicely into $\left(\sum_i im_i\right)^3$, and the linear terms are $2\sum_{i} i^3m_i$. Both of these are $0$ by $(1)$ when $n>3$. The quadratic terms are
$$
-3\sum_i i^3m_i^2-3\sum_{i\neq j}i^2m_ijm_j=-3\sum_{i,j} i^2m_ijm_j=-3\left(\sum_i i^2m_i\right)\left(\sum_j jm_j\right)
$$
which is again $0$ for $n>3$.

---

To summarize these results, let $s_r = \sum_i i^rm_i$. We have shown
$$
\begin{align}
-f^{(1)}(0) &= s_1\\
f^{(2)}(0) &= s_1^2 - s_2\\
-f^{(3)}(0) &= s_1^3 - 3s_1s_2 + 2s_3
\end{align}
$$
The signed Stirling numbers of the first kind are appearing; these resemble the expansion $x^{\underline n}=\sum_k s(n,k)x^k$ of the falling factorial into powers of $k$. No doubt a little more elbow grease will expose a general pattern which can be proved...

**Addendum**: Ok, I can hazard a guess. Notice the sum of the coefficients in each case is $r!$, and the indices of each summand are a partition of $r$, such that the coefficient is the number of permtuations with that cycle structure. This leads to the following guess:

For any permutation $\pi\in S_r$, let $\text{cyc}(\pi)$ the set of the lengths of its cycle lengths. 
$$
\boxed{f^{(r)}(0)\stackrel{?}{=} (-1)^r\sum_{\pi\in S_r}\prod_{c\in \text{cyc}(\pi)}(-1)^{c+1}s_{c}}
$$
If the above were true, your guesses about $a_n$ for $1\le r\le n$ would easily follow.

Comment: When I read such an answer (+1), I realize how poor I am ! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that's already quite helpful!

Answer (score 1):

*This is not an answer.*

I do not know in which context you faced this problem but, many years ago, in the frame of statistical thermodynamics, a researcher in my group worked a similar problem, namely
$$g_n(z)=(1-z)^n\prod_{l=0}^n (1-lz)^{(-1)^l {n\choose l}}$$ and showed, for small values of $n$ quite simple expressions such as
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & g_n(z) \\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 1-2 z \\
 3 & \frac{(1-2 z)^3}{1-3 z} \\
 4 & \frac{(1-4 z) (1-2 z)^6}{(1-3 z)^4} \\
 5 & \frac{(1-4 z)^5 (1-2 z)^{10}}{(1-5 z) (1-3 z)^{10}} \\
 6 & \frac{(1-6 z) (1-4 z)^{15} (1-2 z)^{15}}{(1-5 z)^6 (1-3 z)^{20}} \\
 7 & \frac{(1-6 z)^7 (1-4 z)^{35} (1-2 z)^{21}}{(1-7 z) (1-5 z)^{21} (1-3 z)^{35}}
   \\
 8 & \frac{(1-8 z) (1-6 z)^{28} (1-4 z)^{70} (1-2 z)^{28}}{(1-7 z)^8 (1-5 z)^{56}
   (1-3 z)^{56}} \\
 9 & \frac{(1-8 z)^9 (1-6 z)^{84} (1-4 z)^{126} (1-2 z)^{36}}{(1-9 z) (1-7 z)^{36}
   (1-5 z)^{126} (1-3 z)^{84}} \\
 10 & \frac{(1-10 z) (1-8 z)^{45} (1-6 z)^{210} (1-4 z)^{210} (1-2 z)^{45}}{(1-9
   z)^{10} (1-7 z)^{120} (1-5 z)^{252} (1-3 z)^{120}}
\end{array}
\right)$$ where you can notice some interesting patterns depending on the parity on $n$.

Back to
$$f_n(z)=\prod_{l=0}^n (1-lz)^{(-1)^l {n\choose l}}$$ expansions to $O\left(z^{n+2}\right)$ this gives
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{series} \\
 1 & 1+z+z^2+O\left(z^3\right) \\
 2 & 1-z^2-2 z^3+O\left(z^4\right) \\
 3 & 1+2 z^3+9 z^4+O\left(z^5\right) \\
 4 & 1-6 z^4-48 z^5+O\left(z^6\right) \\
 5 & 1+24 z^5+300 z^6+O\left(z^7\right) \\
 6 & 1-120 z^6-2160 z^7+O\left(z^8\right) \\
 7 & 1+720 z^7+17640 z^8+O\left(z^9\right) \\
 8 & 1-5040 z^8-161280 z^9+O\left(z^{10}\right) \\
 9 & 1+40320 z^9+1632960 z^{10}+O\left(z^{11}\right) \\
 10 & 1-362880 z^{10}-18144000 z^{11}+O\left(z^{12}\right)
\end{array}
\right)$$ which, for $n >1$, seem to be
$$f_n(z)=1+(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!\,\, z^n\left(1+\frac{n^2}{2}z\right)+O\left(z^{n+2}\right)$$

Comment: How do you mean "showed, for small values of $n$ quite simple expressions" -- aren't these simply the definitions of these functions (with the $l=1$ term canceled)?

Comment: @joriki. Unfortunately, I do not have the thesis (it was so long time ago !). I just had a piece of code (written in the very early 80's) giving these (and only these) results.